# How to return an actual instance from a method with a generic return type

Tags: java, generics, types, return

I'm having hard time with creating a type safe behavior, I'll use a general example in order to emphasize my issue:

I have an interface `BoxCreator` which is defined by:

```
public interface BoxCreator{
    public Box create(int id ,List<Box> others);
}
```

and a general `Box` class (A `Box` can contain several other `Box`es) which has methods like `int getId()` ,`Box getInternalBox(int id)`.

Suppose I have a class `Shed implements BoxCreator,Container` (where container is just a general interface with action like add and remove ). I can put new things inside the shed and it'll box them in a `ShedBox` which implements `Box`.

So far so good, the problem arises when I try to make some other class that will do things a little differently, for example `CoolShed extends Shed implements BoxCreator` which will put thing into `CoolBox`es (which extend `ShedBox`).

For now it works but I have several down-casts in the `CoolShed` class (from a general `Box` to `CoolBox`) that might be 'not pretty'.

What I'm looking for is a way to make

`Shed<T extends ShedBox> implements BoxCreator<T>`

And then when implemeting the `CoolShed` I'd just do something like

`CoolShed extends Shed<CoolBox> implemets BoxCreator<CoolBox>`

I was trying to make the various classes generic but but couldn't create a generic `create` method because I can't instantiate a `T` or return one for that matter. So I'm a little lost.

Several notes:

1. The `CoolShed` uses a lot of the `Shed` logic but I'd just to make it use the `CoolBox` class as a container.
2. Currently the `Shed` has an instance of a `BoxCreator` so when creating `CoolShed` I just make `CoolShed` the new creator and it works.
3. `CoolShed` will only have `CoolBox` instances but I wouldn't really mind anything extending `ShedBox` in the `Shed` class.

I just couldn't find a good explanation of how to achieve the desired behavior nor I could tell whether my existing casts are O.K.

I know my example is quite long I'd be happy to make it clearer in any way I can.

**EDIT**

A code template to make the question clearer:

```
public interface BoxCreator{
    public Box create(int id ,List<Box> others);
}

public interface Box{
    void put()
    void addAnother(Box box);
}

public class ShedBox implements Box{
    void put()
    void addAnother(Box box);
}

public class CoolBox extends ShedBox{ //has some extra features but moslty the same
    void put()
    void addAnother(Box box);
}

public interface Container {
    Box addValue(int value);
    Box getBox(int id);
    .
    .
}

public class Shed implements Container, BoxCreator {
    BoxCreator creator;
    SomeCollection<Box> boxes;
    Shed(){
        creator = this;
        .
        .
        .
    }

    Box addValue(int id){
        .
        .//some logic to get otherBox here
        .
        Box box = creator.createBox(id,otherBox);
    }

    Box getBox(int id);

    public Box create(int id ,Box other){
        return new ShedBox(id,others)
    }
}

public class CoolShed extends Shed implements BoxCreator {

    CoolShed(){
        creator = this;
        .
        .
        .
    }

    addValue(int id){
        Box boxAdded = super.add(id)
        .
        .
        .
        CoolBox box = (CoolBox)boxAdded; // The questionable cast
        .
        . //Some logic that involves CoolBox specific actions 
        .
    }

    public Box create(int id ,Box other){
        return new CoolBox(id,others)
    }

}
```

Comment: It's probably better to include a code sample with the various classes to show what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Can CoolShed only contain CoolBox or can it contain any Box?

Comment: @owlstead it's a lot(trust me :) ) of code and most of it is irrelevant to the issue so I'm afraid it'll only confuse people even more, but I've made some general template which might explain the issue better.

Comment: @LeeMeador thank you for pointing this out, `CoolShed` will only have `CoolBox`  instances but I wouldn't really mind anything extending `ShedBox` in the `Shed` class. I've added this information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Previous answer removed)

EDIT: This solution should be better, assuming `others` may contain any box:

```
public interface BoxCreator {
    public Box create(int id, List<Box> others);
}
public class Shed implements BoxCreator {
    @Override
    public ShedBox create(int id, List<Box> others) {
        ...
    }
}
public class CoolShed extends Shed {
    @Override
    public CoolBox create(int id, List<Box> others) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, don't do this:

```
BoxCreator creator;
creator = this;
creator.create(...);
```

Instead, you should either write `this.create(...)` or simply `create(...)`. Then you won't have to cast from `Box` to the desired subclass, since the value returned from `create` will already be of type `ShedBox` or `CoolBox`.

Comment: I've actually tried that option but I could not return a `new ShedBox()` from `create`, maybe my update can make my situation clearer.

Comment: @owlstead I considered using `B` as they're all instances of `Box`, but decided to just go with `T`.

Comment: @Lonenebula Thanks but when using `public Box create(...)` as the implementation signature it issues a warning "unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion " and the usage issues a "unchecked call to create as a raw type of BoxCreator" warning. Using `public T create(...)` does not compile..

Comment: I'm a little confused, if  add returns a `Box` I'd still have to cast it to use it as a `CoolBox`... BTW why is using creator considered bad ?

Comment: @SadStudent `creator` is of type `BoxCreator` while `this` is of type `Shed` or `CoolShed`, so you'll lose information about methods and fields by using `creator`. For instance, in my edit `BoxCreator.create` returns a `Box`, but `Shed.create` returns a `ShedBox`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30091/discussion-between-lone-nebula-and-sadstudent)